# Using nuget package from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

Here's a CSX file that uses the `MathNet.Numerics` nuget package:

```cs
#r "nuget: MathNet.Numerics, 5.0.0"

var normal = new MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal();

Console.WriteLine(normal.CumulativeDistribution(1.0));
```

Result of running the file:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents> dotnet script .\test-math-net-numerics.csx
0.8413447460685429
```

## Question

What's a good way to perform the equivalent in a PowerShell script?

I.e. how can I load, reference and use a nuget package?

## Update

If I run the following first to retrieve the nuget package:

```
Install-Package -Name MathNet.Numerics -ProviderName NuGet -Scope CurrentUser -RequiredVersion 5.0.0 -Destination . -Force -SkipDependencies
```

then the following PowerShell script can load and use the package:

```
$path = Resolve-Path .\MathNet.Numerics.5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\MathNet.Numerics.dll

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($path)

$normal = [MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal]::new()

$normal.CumulativeDistribution(1.0)
```

So I guess now the question is: is this the preferred method of using an arbitrary nuget package from PowerShell?